# Navbar link to specific bootstrap tab without opening new window or tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I'm running Bootstrap 3 with links in my `navbar` to Bootstrap tabs on the 'Category' page, like so:

```
<li><a href="/category/#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
```

On my 'category' page, here's the code I have for my tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in Tab 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I use either html or jquery/javascript so that if people click on either link in the navbar, whether it's from a different page OR from the 'category' page already to go to that page with that tab open?

I am **not** looking to have the link **open in another window or tab**, but rather the same window/tab the user is currently on. (I've already tried this solution by placing `target="_blank"` into the links in the `navbar` and adding `$('#myTabs a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show');` as the javascript. This was not my preferred solution.

Any advice/solutions you might have to offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.
It doesn't account for a variable amount of tabs, but it does the job for 2 tabs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $tab1 = $('#tab1');
  $tab2 = $('#tab2');
  $tablink1 = $('#link_tab1');
  $tablink2 = $('#link_tab2');
  $('#link_tab1 a').on('click', function(){
      
      $tablink1.addClass("active");
      $tab1.addClass("active");
      $tab2.removeClass("active");
      $tablink2.removeClass("active");
  });
  $('#link_tab2 a').on('click', function(){
      $tablink2.addClass("active");
      $tab2.addClass("active");
      $tab1.removeClass("active");
      $tablink1.removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li id="link_tab1" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li id="link_tab2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in Tab 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```